# Error While accessing webservices in java using Android

Tags: android-emulator

I am Trying to accless web services using android but i always have a error listed below 02-12 01:34:55.684: E/StrictMode(672): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d07d98 that was originally bound here

please tell me how to solve this error .
Waiting For Answer